# How do you change the intonation or tone of a word in JavaScript for web browser speech?

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

Short question is, can you tell the browser to read a word in a rising tone or dropping tone?

And this may apply to some other languages or platforms too, besides JavaScript on a web browser.

I read about [speech using JavaScript on a browser on this webpage](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk-Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API).

For example, if you want the browser to pronounce "one" as in "is this the only one?" with a rising tone or intonation, how would that be done?  On the other hand, if you want the browser to pronounce "one" as in "this really is the only one" with a dropping tone or intonation, how would that be done?

The following code can pronounce "one" in Google Chrome version 78.0's console:

(I have 66 voices on my computer, but maybe because it is a Mac with additional voices installed on the OS)

```
((() => {

  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  console.log("How many voices", voices.length, voices);
  voices.forEach(voice => {
    if (voice.name === "Google US English") {
      console.log(voice);
      msg.voice = voice;
    }
  });
  msg.text = "one";
  speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

})());
```

The same applies to proper names: such as "Tainan", if you want the browser to say it with a rising tone or dropping tone, how would that be done?

Another usage is, for some proper names, you may need a hash to "special case" the pronunciation because the default pronunciation is way off or could be better (for example, special case the word "Taipei" so that if the word is in the hash's keys, then read "Tai Bei" instead, which is what native speakers would pronounce). In this case, it is even more important to create rising or dropping tone, and actually, in some languages, such as in Mandarin, I think there are 4 tones, and in Cantonese, there are 9 tones. What is a way to specify it in code?

Comment: Have you tried use SSML in msg.text variable, and adjust pitch in <prosody> tag?

Comment: @Jaroslav I tried and changed the line to `msg.text =  '<prosody pitch="x-high"> but also with a much higher pitch </prosody>'` and it was reading it verbatim, and then I changed it to `msg.ssml = '...'` and it was no use -- the dev tool just stopped altogether. I also tried putting the well format SSML as in https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/ into it and nothing was spoken.

Comment: (actually, the first time it read the SSML verbatim (it read out `<` and `xml` etc), and then second, third time it became all silence as if the system has choked)